# What is the difference between Trait::<T> and <Trait<T>>?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a type whose method I can access through

```
SomeTrait::<T>::method()
```

But I don't understand the difference between that and

```
<SomeTrait<T>>::method()
```

In C++ I would expect this:

```
SomeTrait<T>::method()
```

Are these two different? They both seem to be calling the `<T>` specialisation of `method` on `SomeTrait`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ syntax cannot be used because it is an ambiguous syntax in Rust: in `SomeTrait<T>::method()`, is the first `<` a lesser-than operator, or the beginning of a generic parameters list?

The two methods you refer to are used to disambiguate this:

- `<SomeTrait<T>>` is called the [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name)
- `SomeTrait::<T>` is called the turbofish notation (unofficial name).

Answer (score 3):

`SomeTrait::<T>::method()` and `<SomeTrait<T>>::method()` are the same thing in Rust.

Just a style choice.

Answer (score 2):

#### The C++ syntax is ambiguous

One of the greatest challenge in parsing C++ is the ability to distinguish the use of `<` as either the less-than operator or the beginning of a template-parameter list.

Most of the times, the compiler hides the complexity from you by "cheating", with the C++ parser performing symbol look-up to identify whether whatever is on the left of `<` is a template struct/method or not.

And in some cases this complexity surfaces up; in templates, where the kind of a symbol is unclear, the `template` keyword must be used to distinguish:

```
foo.template get<T>()
```

#### Rust syntax leans toward LL(1)

With the benefit of hindsight, this is one hack that the Rust developers were very keen to avoid.

Therefore, the same expression in Rust will read: `foo.get::<T>()`.

And for consistency, the same syntax is applied to types `Foo::<T>::method()`.